# Python: Put a function "place holder" in another function

Tags: python, pandas, nested

I have  a dataframe (x,y GroupingID).

I want to have a Placeholder function (in which i can insert another function) that:

- Groups df by the grouping ID
- Does some data filtering steps
- Substitutes in the placeholder either function (a, b, c) on the resulting subsetted grp dataframe
- append a value to a var or a dataframe.

This way i can call fun_palceholder with a differet fun in the future wihout rewriting all the data cleaning steps.

```py
data = {
    'grouping_ID': [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3], #group on this
     "x":           np.random.randint(10, size=13),
     "y":           np.random.randint(10, size=13)
}

df= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)


# 3 different functions with different number of arguments
def fun_a (d):
    # Does a linear fit of **x and y**, finds x intercept
    return (x_intercept) 
    
def fun_b (d):  
    #This is an example function, my function is a bit longer  
    return (d['x'].mean())#retuns 1 value
    
def fun_c (d):
    #This is an example function, my function is a bit longer
    return (d["y"].median())#retuns 1 value 


def fun_palceholder (dataframe, either_fun_a_fun_b_fun_c):
    var= []
    # 1. groupby groupID
    for key, grp in df.groupby('grouping_ID'):
        
        # 2. Do otehr operations to the dataframe (filtering etc) 
             **#I AM TYRING TO AVOID REPEATING ALL THE FILTERING STEPS**
             eg. Filtering out all columns with x values below -2
             eg. Removing the bottom half of each grp subset because it is a  
                 backwards measurment 
        
        # 3. Append to var the value of eitehr fun a, fun b, fun c
        var.append( grp, either_fun_a_fun_b_fun_c) 
    return key, var 
    

fun_placeholder(df, fun_a)
#This returns a list of the x intercept values

fun_placeholder(df, fun_b)
fun_placeholder(df, fun_c)

So that if in the future i write a fun_d i can go: 

fun_placeholder (df, fun_d) and avoid having to do the groupby adn filtering on the dataframe.
```

Comment: You mean `df.groupby(['grouping_ID']).agg([func_a, func_b, func_c])`?

Comment: I get an error passing your code

Comment: Gotta rewrite your functions so as it takes a dataframe as single variable, e.g. `def func(d): return d['x'] + d['y']`.

Comment: @QuangHoang I Edited my question with your advice, but i am still getting an error

Comment: `groups = df.groupby('grouping_ID');  
var = [groups.apply(func) for func in [fun_a, fun_b, fun_c]]`

Comment: @QuangHoang, I have edited my question to better explain what i meant. I dont want to run all funciontios toghether, i want to be able to have  placeholder funciton in which i can put my own fun_b, fun_c and in the future a fun_d. So i dont have to write all the setup around the function.

Comment: are you trying to do this: `df.groupby('grouping_ID').agg({"x":[sum, np.mean], "y": [np.median]})` ?

Comment: @DS_UNI, I really must not be explaining myself properely. My real functions aren't mean, media, sum but something more elaborate. Howver before runny any of these funcitons, i need to do quite a lot of steps: 1. groupby the data 2. filter the grouped data. I want to write 1 function placeholder that: 1. grouby the data 2. filter the grouped data. 3. Leaves a placeholder for my other fucntion. So that i don't have to write the otehr steps every time

Comment: I get that your functions are not mean, sum , and median, however my point is would you be using the group by and agg function? is your goal to apply different functions on different columns? in that case your function needs to be applicable on a pd series

Comment: it might be more helpful if you can give an example of the operations you want to do before applying the functions on the groups, that way it will be easier to help you

Comment: in `var.append( grp, either_fun_a_fun_b_fun_c)` do `var.append(  either_fun_a_fun_b_fun_c(grp))`? `either_fun_a_fun_b_fun_c` is already a function are giving it, you can call it as normal

Comment: On the grouped dataset (grp). I want to remove negative values, remove the bottom half of the dataframe, do the abs of some collumns etc. And an example functions fun_a etch is: calculating the x intercept

Comment: @Copperfield, Thanks! That is it. Ok so i can pass a function as an argument of another function.

Comment: yes, you can pass anything as arguments to another function/class, list, numbers, others functions/classes, anything whatsoever...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want correctly, then I believe it would work if your functions takes pd series as input, this is what I mean  :

```
import  numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'grouping_ID': [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3], #group on this
     "x":           np.random.randint(10, size=13),
     "y":           np.random.randint(10, size=13)
}

df= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)


# 3 different functions with different number of arguments
def fun_a (d):
  return (d.sum())#returns 1 value
    
def fun_b (d):    
    return (d.mean())#retuns 1 value
    
def fun_c (d):
    #does something
    return (d.median())#retuns 1 value
```

then you can choose which column you like to aggregate with `agg` like so:

```
df.groupby('grouping_ID').agg({"x":[fun_a, fun_b], "y": [fun_c]})
```